# Mysql locking - How to acquire a lock in the DB for each userId

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking, concurrency

Hi I have a J2EE Server(clustered) that executes requests from multiple users.

I would like that each request of a given user will be handled like so:

```
{
  acquireLockForUser(userId); // i.e. insert a lock row for a dedicated table
  doSomeStuffInDbForUser(user);
  releaseLock(userId);  // i.e. delete a lock row from the dedicated table
}
```

This will make sure that each user request will be handled by a single thread of my servers.

Whats the way to achieve that? (Is it possible to insert into a table 'userLock' by id and lock it? how to insert\fetch from this "lock" table?)

Comment: I guess this is what you're looking for: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Answer (score 0):

```
GET_LOCK('rick');
...
RELEASE_LOCK('rick');
```

During `...`, any other thread trying to do `GET_LOCK('rick')` would be blocked.

Will that work for your application?

Be aware of the caveats:  A disconnect (eg, network glitch) will release the lock.  Multiple locks need some care.  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

> ... make sure that each user request will be handled by a single thread of my servers.

Why do you feel the need to do this?

Channelling *all* the processing of a [clustered] application into a bottleneck where only one process can work with the database at any one time is *completely alien* to the way that way that modern, Relational Databases work.

I would suggest that something like [Serialisable] **Transactions** are better suited to your needs.